# How to query collection with Linq.Expressions

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I built a custom IQueryable provider. The provider transforms query for example

```
c.PurchaseDate == new DateTime(2011, 11, 29) && c.Name == "Elizabeth Brown"
```

from underlying code into System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

Now I need to run them against this collection with Linq query

```
IQueryable<Customer> customers = _customers.AsQueryable();
```

Can anyone tell me how to query the collection with Expression?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
//Query = c.PurchaseDate == new DateTime(2011, 11, 29) && c.Name
    // == "Elizabeth Brown" )
IQueryable<Customer> customers = _customers.AsQueryable<Customer>();

//Predicate parameter
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), 
                                                          "customer");

//Create left expression
Expression left = Expression.Property(parameter, typeof(Customer)
                                     .GetProperty("PurchaseDate"));
Expression right = Expression.Constant(new DateTime(2011, 11, 29));
Expression leftExp = Expression.Equal(left, right);

//Create right expression tree
left = Expression.Property(parameter, typeof(Customer).GetProperty("Name"));
right = Expression.Constant("Elizabeth Brown", typeof(string));
Expression rightExp = Expression.Equal(left, right);

//Combine the expressions into expression tree
Expression expressionTree = Expression.AndAlso(leftExp, rightExp);

//Create an expression tree that represents the expression
MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { customers.ElementType },
    customers.Expression,
    Expression
               .Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>
                 (expressionTree, new ParameterExpression[] { parameter }));

// Create an executable query from the expression tree.
IQueryable<Customer> results = 
                customers.Provider.CreateQuery<Customer>(methodCall);

// Enumerate the results
foreach (Customer customer in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", customer.Name, customer.PurchaseDate);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

I finished with the task this way. IQueryable is really wonderfull stuff. Enjoy!

Comment: Wow! This is impressive! The line `Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(Customer)` should have `parameter` instead of `pe` right?

Comment: Actually in your real-life code you have to override an abstract ExpressionVisitor class to Visit and extrude these values in runtime, but for the purpose of demonstration I created these three Expression values in static context.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've made a mistake preparing the sample, but now corrected. This code represents only the basic functionality, just to understand how this technique works. To demonstrate that I created both left and right expressions of lambda clause corresponding c.PurchaseDate == new DateTime(2011, 11, 29) && c.Name == "Elizabeth Brown" The ParameterExpression parameter defines only the type and parameter c itself.