# Create Expression for List.Any clause

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

Consider this hierarchy of classes.

```
class Event
{
    public Attendees[] AttendeesList;
}

class Attendees
{
    public ComplexProperty Property;
    public object Value;
}

class ComplexProperty
{

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // There are constants.
        ComplexProperty constproperty = new ComplexProperty();
        object constValue = 5;

        // consider this linq query:
        Event evnt = new Event();

        var result = evnt.AttendeesList.Any((attnds) => attnds.Property == constproperty && attnds.Value == constValue);


        // I want to create an Expression tree for above linq query. I need something like this:
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Attendees));
        Expression left = Expression.Property(parameter, typeof(ComplexProperty).GetProperty("Property"));
        // complete this piece.......

    }
}
```

I want to create a `Linq.Expressions.Expression` for  `evnt.AttendeesList.Any((attnds) => attnds.Property == constproperty && attnds.Value == constValue);`
 this linq query. [How to query collection with Linq.Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876059/how-to-query-collection-with-linq-expressions) looks similar, but I have `Any` in my linq expression.

Please help.

Comment: Your example code is exactly the code you've asked for... what's the question here?

Comment: I updated the question. I want to be able to make Expression tree for given linq query. This expression will be used as filtering criteria in some other part of code.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a start:

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Attendees));
Expression left = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "Property"), Expression.Constant(constproperty));

var objType = constValue == null ? typeof(object) : constValue.GetType();
var convertLeft = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(parameter, "Value"), objType);
var convertRight = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(constValue), objType);
Expression right = Expression.Equal(convertLeft, convertRight);
Expression joined = Expression.And(left, right);

var anyMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name=="Any" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2).First().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Attendees));
var call = Expression.Call(anyMethod, Expression.Constant(evnt.AttendeesList, typeof(IQueryable<Attendees>)), Expression.Lambda(joined, parameter));
```

I changed Value to type `int` for ease of use. If you want to keep it as an object, you will need to add a Expression.Convert() call in the `right` Expression.

Comment: Thnaks Rob. Can you help me with Expression.Convert()  in the right expression. I will get to know type of constValue at runtime, and i want to support all operators ('==', '!=', '<', '>', '<=', '>='), so convert would be needed as i donnt think i can do these operations on objects, without type casting.