# Build Lambda Expression Tree in ComplexTypes with Key Value logic

Tags: linq, lambda, expression

Hi I Use Linq Expression BuildTree logic ,and at last compile and run.

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expr, paramUser).Compile(); 

class MyClass
{
List<Param> params{get;set;}
}

class Params{
string Key,
string Value
}
```

I want to create dynamic expression in runtime ,pass key and value parameters and build my expression tree how can I do it for these case.I Build my expression like that.

```
if (ExpressionType.TryParse(r.Operator, out tBinary))
            {
                var right = this.StringToExpression(r.TargetValue, propType);
                return Expression.MakeBinary(tBinary, propExpression, right);
            }
            else if (r.Operator == "IsMatch")
            {
                return Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Regex).GetMethod("IsMatch",
                        new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(RegexOptions) }),
                    propExpression,
                    Expression.Constant(r.TargetValue, typeof(string)),
                    Expression.Constant(RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, typeof(RegexOptions))
                );
            }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395072/create-expression-for-list-any-clause I want to do that these post but I failed to work with System.Collections.Generic.List